# Paypal PDT will only return billing OR shipping info in variables. If a cust edits both addresses on Paypal I need to know that info

Tags: php, paypal

When receiving PDT variables from Paypal I only get the shipping address.  If a cust changes both the billing and shipping addresses I need to know that for my records.  I have sent the billing address to Paypal using address1, address2, city, state, zip to prefill the fields on Paypal's site but if I try to get the billing address from the PDT using those same variables I get nothing.  Using address_street, address_city, address_state, and address_zip to access the shipping address via PDT does return the shipping info.  Can anyone tell me how to get both addresses from Paypal's PDT?  I don't have much luck with Paypal's tech support.

Comment: ugghhh pdt. Fought with that beast a long time ago. Which API are you using? (classic or REST)

Comment: I'm using the PDT in the Standards.  I'm not sure which API.  Thanks for asking, but I think Andrew Angell gave me the answer I needed.

Answer (score 1):

One of the advantages of PayPal for buyers is that they don't have to share their billing information with sellers.  This helps protect them.  As such, it's by design that all PDT/IPN/GetTransactionDetails will return is a single address, which is considered the shipping address.

If you want to collect both billing and shipping separately you'll need to collect that on your site prior to sending the user over to PayPal, but then that sort of defeats the purpose of "express" checkout for people because now you've got them filling out forms instead of just signing in to PayPal to complete payment.

Comment: That makes sense.  I am collecting the cust info on my site, but if they change the billing address and add a shipping on Paypal I want to know what edits were made to both.  I guess I'll have to work around it.  Thanks for such a fast answer.